# Eliminate last 2 char based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, conditional-statements

I use this condition in case to compare string and eliminate last 2 char

```
right(tr.item,2) = '%bx' then left(tr.item,len(tr.item)-2)
```

but I want multiple conditions and eliminate last 2 chars.

I tried to execute this statement

```
right(tr.item,2) like ('%bx','%cx','%ax') then left(tr.item,len(tr.item)-2)
```

But I got an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this logic

```
(case when right(tr.item, 2) in ('bx', 'cx', 'ax')
     then left(tr.item, len(tr.item) - 2)
     else tr.item
 end)
```

You don't need wildcards (ala `like`) if you are using `right()`.  And conditional logic in SQL is provided via the `case` expression.

Comment: You are right I removed wildcard and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..you need a OR

```
  ((right(tr.item,2) like ('%bx'))
   or 
  (right(tr.item,2) like ('%cx'))
  or
 (right(tr.item,2) like ('%ax')))
  then left(tr.item,len(tr.item)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using RIGHT function, I don't think you need '%'. So you can do:
 right(tr.item,2) IN ('bx','cx','ax')